# How to remove read-only property from files that WERE under svn without svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This may sound as a duplicate question but is not, I already read the other similar ones and does not apply to me. So this is what happened...

I had one computer with Tortoise SVN installed and a project under that control, when I got a new computer all I did was to copy the project folder from old computer and save it in the new computer.

I did not install SVN on new computer because I will no longer need it but the problem is when I try to edit anything in the project I can't because it get the error "Access to path is denied".

I tried simply removing the read-only property from windows but it didn't work, I assume the files have some kind of locking from SVN, so how can I remove that locking?  If possible, without having to install again SVN.

Also, I'm trying to edit from Visual Studio and when saving I get the error.

Comment: Check NTFS permissions for unaccessble files.

Comment: That didn´t work. I should probably mention that I'm trying to edit from Visual Studio and when saving I get the error.